# Get new image dimensions for an image when given min-width & min-height

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, css

I'm looking for a function that will take in an Image object, a min width and a min height it will return a size object (or any other object with a width and a height property) with the new dimensions of the image.

For example if I passed an image that has original dimensions of:

> 1024x768 (width x height)

into this function with:

> minimum width: 256, minimum height: 206

The function would return a size object:

> new width: 274, new height: 206

This allows an image to fill a space while preserving the aspect ratio of the image.

Thanks for any help anyone can give.

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Have you tried writing such a function? What issues are you having?

Comment: I don't know how you guys did it but looking at it again I figured it out, simple pimple as you said, I hate it when the simplest things can take the longest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Size GetMinimalDimensions(int origwidth, int origheight, int minwidth, int minheight)
{
    double scale1, scale2;
    scale1 = (double)origwidth / minwidth;
    scale2 = (double)origheight / minheight;
    if (scale1 > scale2) {
        return new Size((int)Math.Round(origwidth / scale2), minheight);
    }
    return new Size(minwidth, (int)Math.Round(origheight / scale1));
}
```

Pretty easy. Why could not you do it yourself? oO

Comment: Thanks for this, it was really easy I was just going down the complete wrong track, but looking at it again. I figured it out, thanks for this. I will still mark this as the answer, thanks for this!

Comment: the last line should be `return new Size(minwidth, (int)Math.Round(origheight / scale1));`